# Using RStudio Connection Pane to connect with a PostgreSQL database

Tags: r, postgresql, database-connection, rstudio

We have a PostgreSQL database at work. Every time I want to connect to it, I'm manually executing the following code to build my connection and it works just fine.

```
    library(RPostgreSQL)
    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
                     dbname   = "company_xy",
                     host     = "db.company_xy.de",
                     port     = 5432,
                     user     = rstudioapi::askForPassword("User"),
                     password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password!"))
```

I now want to start using the Connections pane but despite trying in multiple ways to set it up, I never got it working. This is the process I followed as described in the [RStudio documentation](http://db.rstudio.com/databases/postgresql/):

1.Click on New Connection
2.Select PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)
3.In the parameters window I paste in the following code:

```
    Driver = "PostgreSQL",
    Server = "db.company_xy.de",
    Database = "company_xy",
    UID = "my_username",
    PWD = "my_password",
    Port = 5432
```

I always receive the following error message:

> Failure. :2.99: unexpected symbol 1: library(DBI) con <-
>   dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={PostgreSQL
>   Unicode(x64)};Driver   = "PostgreSQL

I tried removing the parenthesis and using different kind of separators between the parameters ({}, ;) but to no end. The drivers for odbc and DBI are installed.

Can anyone spot a coding mistake or did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work provided that you remove the double quotes and spaces, and replace the commas by semicolons.

So your parameters window should look like that:

```
Server=db.company_xy.de;
Database=company_xy;
UID=my_username;
PWD=my_password;
Port=5432;
```

Note that you don't need to specify the driver since you already chose it when you selected `PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)` in the previous window.

Actually it seems that the point of this parameters windows is just to build the connection string that you can see below it. So IMO it's more direct to set the connection from your R script (or console):

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  driver = "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)",
  Server = "db.company_xy.de",
  Database = "company_xy",
  UID = rstudioapi::askForPassword("User"),
  PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password!"),
  Port = 5432
)
```

or, if you like connection strings:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(), 
  .connection_string = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=db.company_xy.de;Database=company_xy;UID=my_username;PWD=my_password;Port=5432;"
)
```

but this latter method does not allow you to use `rstudioapi::askForPassword`.

In both cases the connection will appear in your Connections pane.

Maybe in the future you won't need to use `odbc` for that:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/postgresql-in-connection-tab/1817/4

Comment: I tried the three methods provided by you and it didnt't work. Excecuting the code both from the Connections Pane and the Console I receive the following error message: **Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 08001: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_username"**. I tried writing the password as string, without the rstudioapi:: but I receive the same error message. I know the password is correct since using the first method described in my post is working. (Thanks so far :)

Comment: Ok, that's a different problem. Does your password contain non-ASCII characters? Or characters among `[]{}(),;?*=!@`? Because I've found that thread: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Problem-with-special-characters-in-password-when-using-SQLDriverConnect-td5755239.html

Comment: Yes I have a "+" in my password. I followed the instructions in the link you provided and found a solution. Enclosing my password in curly brackets {my_password} did the trick. It works now. Kick Ass! **Thanks a lot :)**