# RStudio Connections Pane: PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) does not appear in the list anymore

Tags: postgresql, rstudio

I'm using the Connections Pane in RStudio to connect to a PostgresSQL Database. A while ago, I started this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431947/using-rstudio-connection-pane-to-connect-with-a-postgresql-database) and finally managed to set it up.

After installing my System new (Win10, R3.5.0, RStudio1.1.453), I tried to retrace my steps to set it up again, but couldn't do so. After opening the Connections Pane the only existing sources I see are "Livy" and "Spark". Postgres and all other connections are missing.

What I tried so far is to install PostgresSQL on my Computer. I also installed the `RPostgres`, `odbc` and `DBI` Packages in the hope that the Postgres option would appear in the list agian, but to no end.

There is this Troubleshooting [Post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011264307) on RStudio, but it didnt help me so far.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! The odbc Driver was not installed when I installed PostgreSQL on my system. Here a couple of hints for others who might have the same problem:

Open RStudio and type in:

```
odbc::odbcListDrivers()
```

If postgres is not listed, you can, at least thats what I did, go tot the PostgresSQL page and download the newest Version and install it. If for whatever reason, the driver is not installed, open the

```
Application Stack Builder (it comes with the postgres installation)
```

navigate to the folder Database Drivers and select "psqlODBC 32 and/or 64". Install them. It will just do the trick!

Comment: I am on a mac and have the exact same issue as you described. This solution unfortunately did not work for me. I installed all the ODBC drivers using homebrew as is recommended here https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/ . This also didn't work.